# Can anything be a system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I was doing some problems on Newton's Laws of Motion, and I found out that the solution arbitrarily considered anything as a system.

[image]

For example, in this question on pulleys, the solution simply took $m_2$ and $m_3$ as a system (a bigger block) with mass $(m_2+m_3)$, and then solved for acceleration. When can we do that and under what conditions? If similar such problems are given, is this approach physically valid? What can and cannot be taken as a system?

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental object of classical mechanics is the point-like mass. You can apply Newton's laws to it, as well as derived theorems involving angular momentum or kinetic energy. All three theorems have the same form:
$$\frac{dX}{dt}=\sum_iD_i$$
where $X$ is a kinematical quantity related to the system (linear momentum, angular momentum, kinetic energy), and the $D_i$ are quantities related to interactions (respectively resultant, torque and power).

You can choose any set of point-like masses as a system, in which case you simply add up those theorems. You can do it blindly, but in practice, the result is known in advance.

For example, when you add up Newton's second law for any number of point-like masses, you get a formula that looks exactly like Newton's second law except that:

- The linear momentum that appears in the left-hand side is that of the center of mass as if it was carrying the total mass of the system (by definition of the center of mass).
- The resultant in the right-hand side contains only external forces, as internal forces cancel each other out (with Newton's third law).

This is why you can choose any subsystem in your exercise. There's no fundamental difference between the "total system" and "any subsystem", so it all comes to do what's practical.

With Newton's second law, the main strategy when choosing a system is: are there forces that you don't want to study and that would disappear as internal forces with a clever choice of system?

Answer (score 0):

I will purely be answering based on the question you gave, the block m2 and m3 have the same acceleration. So while calculating the net force, it would be easy to consider them a system as their accelerations are same. you can write T1 - (m2+m3)g= -(m2+m3)a. This made our work easier. So while solving such macroscopic world problems (Newtonian mechanics), you can consider anything that makes your work easier, a system. You could have also considered m1 and m2 the system by writing the forces on both M1 and M2 in the following way,

T1 - m1g + T1 - T2 - m2g= m1a - m2a

But the above won't help you much.

While solving problems, 2 objects with same acceleration, or 2 objects which have an action reaction pair acting on them can be considered the system, as this will make it easier to solve the problem.

IN the end, it depends on you, what you want to consider a system, there is no hard and fast rule.

Hope this helped
I might not be so experienced in the field of quantum mechanics but I have solved quite a few numericals like the one you sent :)

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up! However, when you took $M_1$ and $M_2$ as a system, shouldn't their combined mass be $M_1+M_2$?

Comment: I did! I wrote the forces on both and the acceleration of both! You can't write (M1 +M2)a because both the masses' acceleration differ! SO you individually write the masses and their accelerations and add them up. the acceleration of M1 is +a and of M2 is -a

Comment: @stonecraftbros If it did help you out do let me know, also if you have any other doubts